# How do you separate phone number and cellnumber that are in one column?

Tags: sql-server

Cell numbers and Phone numbers are in one column and they are in different format eg(021-5454456,0213434559, 021 3469564) and cell numbers are in this format(0784595984,078 7894836). I want to display only cell numbers.

Comment: you can use like that `select * from tblName where col not like '021%'`

Comment: I think it is not necessary that all phone start with 021.So throw different  sample data in correct format.Also don't forget to take back of table

Comment: It might also be worth saying that this is absolutely not a good way to store data in a database.

Comment: I agree @Slyvain but unfortunately the database was not created by me. I was given to create a report using that bad design of database.

Comment: @KumarHarsh yes not all landlines start with 021, what i did is that I used "LIKE" instead of NOT LIKE, I collected all the kinds of cellphone numbers and displayed them.